# How can I convert a REG_BINARY value from the registry into a string ? (vb.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, binary, registry, string-conversion

I have a registry value which is stored as a binary value (REG_BINARY) holding information about a filepath. The value is read out into an byte array. But how can I transform it into a readable string?

I have read about system.text.encoding.ASCII.GetString(value) but this does not work. As far as I got to know the registry value is arbitrary binary data and not ASCII which is the reason for the method to produce useless data.

Does anybody know how I can convert the data?

Sample:
(A piece of the entry)

```
01 00 00 00 94 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 63 00 3A 00 5C 00 
70 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 6d 00 65 00 
5C 00 67 00 65 00 6D 00 65 00 69 00 6E 00 73 00 61 00 
6D 00 65 00 20 00 64 00 61 00 74 00 65 00 69 00 65 00 
6E 00 5C
```

Due to the regedit this is supposed to be:

```
............c.:.\.p.r.o.g.r.a.m.m.e.\.g.e.m.e.i.n.s.a.m.e. .d.a.t.e.i.e.n.\
```

The entry itself was created from Outlook. It's an entry for an disabled addin item (resiliency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not *arbitrary* binary data - it's text data in *some* kind of encoding. You need to find out what the encoding is.

I wouldn't be surprised if `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(value)` worked - but if that doesn't, please post a sample (in hex) and I'll see what I can do. What does the documentation of whatever's put the data in there say?

EDIT: It looks like Encoding.Unicode is your friend, but starting from byte 12. Use

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 12, bytes.Length-12)
```

Comment: Encoding.Unicode does not work either. I hope the sample will help?

Comment: The reason it doesnt work is because of the leading 12 bytes. Ditch the first 12 bytes and pass the rest to Unicode.GetString().

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and i solved in this way:

I had declared a variable as:

```
Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
```

Then I do this in a loop:

```
    For Each Val As String In ValueName
        data = k.GetValue(Val)
        ListRecent.Items.Add(Val & ": " & encoding.GetString(data))
    Next
```

So in listbox called "ListRecent" I have obtained the complete list of recent

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Function Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(name as String) as Object
```

Also look at `System.Text.Encoding` and `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`