# Convert Reg_Binary to human readable form

Tags: c#, binary, registry

*I have seen countless articles and forum posts about this, but sadly none of this could help me.*

I simply want to convert the Reg_Binary Value from a key to a string that is human readable.

For example:

[image]

And I have tried to convert it via some online converters. And I've written a small program to convert it:

```
TextboxString.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes, 12, Bytes.Length - 12);
```

I have tried every encoding but from all this attempts i only get rubbish.

Online Converter:

[image]

Program:

[image]

Comment: have a look into base64 string, namely `Convert.ToBase64String`. Another way will be converting it into hexadecimal string, which is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you expect to see when you say "human readable".

Comment: A little more research tells me that the encoding seems to be in unicode format, but need to start from byte 12, `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 12, bytes.Length-12)`. Comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/how-can-i-convert-a-reg-binary-value-from-the-registry-into-a-string-vb-net?rq=1)

Comment: @john I have the task from the company to read that out but because of lack of experience i sadly dont know what to expect

Comment: @lamandy And yes that is very correct. I have done my research but sadly nothing helped jet. And i will take a look at the base64 stuff.

Comment: I'd go with lamandy's suggestion then, or you could try `BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "")` to get the value as a hexadecimal string similar to how it is presented in the registry.

Comment: RegBinary is just arbitrary binary data. Whether it represents a human readable string, and in which encoding, depends on specific key\value. You cannot expect that _any_ RegBinary is a string in some encoding.

Comment: @Evk What do most RegBinarys represent?

Comment: They can represent absolutely anything. Like, what most files on your filesystem represent?

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884(v=vs.85).aspx), REG_BINARY means binary data in any form so unicode/UTF8 encoding does not make any sense.

Comment: @EVk So it simply does not really make sense to try to convert it?

Comment: If you don't know anything about what this value represents - then converting using encoding is not what you want. You can convert it to hex string (like is displayed on your first screenshot) if you want to display it in user interface.